# Drop down menu - Successful in trying the code but does not appear on Weebly live site

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigation bar.  I have a drop down effect working successfully in my test environment. It doesn't work on my target website (the menu "Archive" should show drop down effect).

Here's a URL to where it does not work properly.

http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/back-stage.html

Here is the markup that I am using, which **does work** in test, but not at the URL above.

```html
<style type="text/css"> 

  body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

  #wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 0; 
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #366b82;
  }

  .navbar  {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #54879d;
  }

  .navbar li  {
    height: auto;
    width: 147px; 
    float: left; 
    text-align: center; 
    list-style: none; 
    font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #366b82;     
  }

  .navbar a {       
    padding: 18px 0; 
    border-left: 1px solid #54879d;
    border-right: 1px solid #1f5065;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color: #54879d;}

  .navbar li ul  {
    display: none;
    height: auto;         
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;        
  }

  .navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;         
  }

  .navbar li ul li {background-color: #54879d;}

  .navbar li ul li a  {
    border-left: 1px solid #1f5065; 
    border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; 
    border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065; 
  }

  .navbar li ul li a:hover {background-color: #366b82;}


</style>       



</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/live.html">Live</a>
      <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/news.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/calculators.html">Calculators</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/knowledge.html">Knowledge</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archive</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/jan-2017.html">Jan 2017</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/feb-2017.html">Feb 2017</a></li>
        </ul>         
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://quantsrecord.weebly.com/contact.html">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `overflow-y` set, you need to remove it. Change this:

```
<div id="611390739829550513" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;" class="wcustomhtml" align="center">
```

To this:

```
<div id="611390739829550513" style="width: 100%;" class="wcustomhtml" align="center">
```

Comment: Hello, Did I get you wrong? I don't have <div id="611390739829550513" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;" class="wcustomhtml" align="center">

Comment: Yes you do. Are you at all familiar with developer tools? Look at your page man.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">click here</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">sub Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Sorry, I copy paste the code and it doesn't show any drop down effect at all, could you plz show me more about it?

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.  Follow the link and see what OP's actual markup looks like, and you'll see that workarounds like this aren't going to solve the  issue.

Comment: You can use bootstrap css and js.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you  mean, could you plz show me the code?

Answer (score 0):

**Teaching you how to troubleshoot**
You can test / prove these things with your browser's developer tools.  They are SUPER powerful and permit you to not only see the markup and CSS affecting any element, they also allow you to "play" with the styles so that you can see if different changes fix the problem.  Here's one of many articles that might help you learn to troubleshoot: http://bigemployee.com/4-simple-techniques-to-quickly-debug-and-fix-your-css-code-in-almost-any-browser/

**Explaining the problem**
The problem is due to some markup that (presumably) Weebly adds to your site.  The  `nav` markup is wrapped in this element:

```
<div id="611390739829550513" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;" class="wcustomhtml" align="center"><!-- your nav here --></div>
```

Due to this element, which has the inline-style of `overflow-y: hidden;`, your drop-down does not show up (even though your styles make it `display: block`, it cannot show because it is below / outside the wrapper).

If you can find a way to modify that markup, or add a style to address that element and override the `overflow-y: hidden`, you will be able to make the element appear.

ONE THING that you could do potentially is get this in some styles:

```
div#611390739829550513 {
    overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```

However, it would be preferable to *remove* the style from the element if possible.

Lastly, if you do this, you'll need to fix your navigation, because at narrower widths it "wraps" and the "Contact" menu item appears below the rest of the nav instead of inline.

Comment: where should I add the following code in to my code? div#611390739829550513 {
    overflow-y: visible !important;
}